# How to refactor Php code inside a Laravel view blades

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6

I am trying to write some code inside a laravel blade as shown below

```
@can('identical_trademark_local_show')
@php
    $trimmed_payment_id=Str::substr($Payment->payment_id,0,9);

    if($trimmed_payment_id=='AlYAFI:IL')
    {
        <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="{{ route('admin.identical-trademark-locals.show', $Payment->id) }}">
            trans('global.view')
        </a>"

    }
    if($trimmed_payment_id=='AlYAFI:SL')
    {
        <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="{{ route('admin.similarlocals.show', $Payment->id) }}">
            trans('global.view')
        </a>

    }
    if($trimmed_payment_id=='AlYAFI:SI')
    {
        <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="{{ route('admin.similarinternationals.show', $Payment->id) }}">
            trans('global.view')
        </a>
    }
@endphp
@endcan
```

The problem is that am getting a syntax error

> syntax error, unexpected '<'

Comment: Please don't use image for your code - write it directly and we will help you format it

Comment: use @if please..

Comment: @ChristopheHubert changed

Comment: You can check my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the mustache `{{ }}` symbol inside a `@php` block and you need to write your HTML code outside of your `@php` block

You'd be better off writing everything in blade syntax, one of the way to do it is as follow:

```
@can('identical_trademark_local_show')
        @php
            $trimmed_payment_id=Str::substr($Payment->payment_id,0,9);
        @endphp

        @if($trimmed_payment_id=='AlYAFI:IL')
            <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="{{ route('admin.identical-trademark-locals.show', $Payment->id) }}">
                trans('global.view')
            </a>
        @endif

        @if($trimmed_payment_id=='AlYAFI:SL')
            <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="{{ route('admin.similarlocals.show', $Payment->id) }}">
                trans('global.view')
            </a>
        @endif

        @if($trimmed_payment_id=='AlYAFI:SI')
            <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="{{ route('admin.similarinternationals.show', $Payment->id) }}">
                trans('global.view')
            </a>
        @endif
@endcan
```

**NOTE**

You should avoid the `@php` block and instead pass on the value from your controller.

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to ask more question here - we're always happy to help